# LogLevel.INFO printed as ERROR [STDERR] in Jboss log, what is wrong?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I´ve been using MyEclipse to reverese engineer some database tables to EJBs. In this process, MyEclipse creates a class called LogUtil, which looks like this:

```
public class LogUtil {

private static final Logger logger;

static {
    logger = Logger.getLogger("SupplierDatabaseEJBPU");
    logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
}

public static void log(String info, Level level, Throwable ex) {
    logger.log(level, info, ex);
}

public static Logger getLogger() {
    return logger;
}
```

}

It will then insert logging into a number of generated methods, for example:

```
public void save(PurchaseOrderInput entity) {
LogUtil.log("saving PurchaseOrderInput instance", Level.INFO, null);
try {
    entityManager.persist(entity);
    LogUtil.log("save successful", Level.INFO, null);
} catch (RuntimeException re) {
    LogUtil.log("save failed", Level.SEVERE, re);
    throw re;
}
}
```

I´m not that experienced with loggers, so maybe this is very easy...

When I run for example the method posted above, the following is what I get in my server.log.

```
2011-02-23 09:22:30,301 ERROR [STDERR] 2011-feb-23 09:22:28 se.ahlens.intranet.apps.supplierdatabase.LogUtil log
INFO: save successful
```

I find this very confusing. Is it supposed to look like this? I expected something along:

```
2011-02-23 00:05:30,348 INFO  [SupplierDatabaseEJBPU] INFO: save successful
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that two loggers are chained (the date is printed twice). Assumption: The first one is logging with level info to the console. Jboss intercepts the system output streams and logs them using its own logger (which uses the error level)

Comment: Sounds like a good explanation. I rewrote the genereted logging, should hopefully work better now.